# length of list of strings in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have no Idea how to complete my code and need help.

The function I need should be able to calculate the number of characters in a list of strings.

For example:

```
charLena (createStrLst ["avd", "d4sf"] ["asvd","a2e","bdsh"])    --output is 7 (Total length of the first List)

charLenb (createStrLst ["avd", "d4sf"] ["asvd","a2e","bdsh"])    --output is 11 (Total length of the second List)
```

Those are the functions I have and can use:

```
data StrLst = StrLst [String] [String] deriving (Eq)
StrLst :: [String] -> [String] -> StrLst 

createStrLst :: [String] -> [String] -> StrLst 
numa :: StrLst -> Int             --number of strings in a
numb :: StrLst -> Int             --number of strings in b
lena :: StrLst -> Int -> Int      --length of (i+1)-th string in a
lenb :: StrLst -> Int -> Int      --length of (i+1)-th string in b

createStrLst  a b = (StrLst a b)
numa (StrLst a b) = length a
numb (StrLst a b) = length b
lena (StrLst a b) i = length (a!!i)
lenb (StrLst a b) i = length (b!!i)
```

Now I need the length of the first List of Strings `charLena` and the second List of Strings `charLenb`.

I am also allowed to use `map` and recursion and just basic commands of haskell (nothisng else)

But how can I map through StrLst datatype??

Comment: So what have you tried? Where are you stuck? What don't you understand? We're willing to help, but this is not a do-your-homework service.

Comment: I don't know how to map through `StrLst` datatype because this is new to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StrLst` is not a list, so you can't use `map` directly. However, the two functions you are supposed to write appear responsible for deciding which list to map over:

```
charLena :: StrLst -> Int
charLena (StrLst a _) = ...

charLenb :: StrLst -> Int
charLenb (StrLst _ b) = ...
```

`a` and `b` are the first and second lists, respectively, stored in the `StrLst` value received as an argument. Each has type `[String]`, and so is suitable for use as an argument to `map`.

---

Update: Since you don't have the ability to pattern match on the `StrLst` value, there is no way for you to get direct access to either list. The only thing you can do is use `lena` and `lenb` to get lengths of individual strings from either list. In order to know what indices are valid arguments to `lena`/`lenb`, you need to use `numa`/`numb` to find the length of either list, then construct a range. For example, `[0..numa s - 1]` would give you a list of valid indices into the first list of `s`.

Once you have the index list, you can map the partially applied function `lena s` over it to give you all the individual string lists for list A, which you can then sum up to give you the return value of `charLena`.

```
charLena s = let indices = [0..numa s - 1]
                 lengths = ... -- use map here
             in ...  -- add up the values in lengths here.
```

`charLenb` will be similar, but using `numb` and `lenb` instead.

Comment: I did what you recommended  `charLenb(StrLst _ b) = lengthLst b`  and LengthLst is a function I wrote that calculate the length of [String] but it don't work.   I get this error "Not in scope: data constructor `StrLst' "

Comment: Are you importing the data type from a module that doesn't export the data constructor? `StrLst` is the name used in the type definition you provided.

Comment: yes I did `import Types (StrLst, createStrLst, numa , numb, lena, lenb)`

Comment: Ok, then you appear to have no way to get an individual list from the value, only individual string lengths via `lena` and `lenb`.

Comment: `Types` appears to be providing a quite ugly and non-idiomatic interface to `StrLst`.

Comment: @karmo20 The import `import Types (StrLst)` only imports the `StrLst` type constructor. If you want the data constructor, you must use `import Types (StrLst(StrLst))` or `import Types (StrLst(..))`.

Comment: Almost right: the range should be `[0.. numa s - 1]`, not `[0 .. numa s]`.